# Fusing images from 4 different angles

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, bounding-box, fusion

I am trying to predict 3D bounding boxes for images of a same object from 4 different angles.

I now want to fuse all those images and see which one predicted accurately.
How can I do that?
Any approach or open source github repo?

Thanks!

[image: This is the back part of the same car]

[image: This is the front part of the car]

[image: This is the front part of the car]

[image: This is the another side of the same car]

Comment: It would be better to provide more details about your problem (object types, image samples, desired output, etc) and also describe your current approach and the results you have. Use the following question as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69914993/1435741

Comment: Ok I'll add the image samples so that it makes it easier for you.

Comment: The following github repo is the one I am using to generate the 3D bounding boxes and use it for multiple angles. I hope you get an idea of what's going on https://github.com/skhadem/3D-BoundingBox